# linked list not working properly, head updated instead

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a problem with the following linked list code, but i'm not sure what it is. Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm using this code in some larger code where i update records, but it never reaches the "creating new record" section. It is as if the main code is updating the head pointer instead thus always resulting in a favourable comparison.

Thanks in advance. I've been racking my brains out trying to figure out what the problem is.

```
struct l_list *find_name(const char *name)
{
    struct l_list *tmp=0;
    if(records==0) { // First record
        head=new l_list;
        head->name=name;
        head->next=0;
        tail=head;
        records++;
        return head;
    } 
    else {
        tmp=head;
        while(tmp!=0)
        {
        if(!std::strcmp(tmp->name,name)) 
        {
            cout << "Returning existing record with value: " << tmp->number << " name:" <<      tmp->name << endl;
            return tmp;
        }
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    // No first and no existing records
    cout << "Creating new record" << endl;
    tail->next=new l_list;
    tail=tail->next;
    tail->name=name;
    tail->next=0;
    records++;
    return tail;
}
```

I'm calling this from main with:
    struct records *tmp=find_name("Max");

then :

```
tmp=find_name("Eva");
```

Once i get the struct i update it like so:

```
tmp->number=1;
```

Or even updating the name:

```
tmp->name="Peter";
```

So by passing a string to the function it will either create a new record and return it or give an existing record and return that. Problems might not be apparent in the output, but when you put it in a for(;;) loop in main it will
mess up.

The struct is as follows:

```
struct records {
      const char *name;
      struct records *next;
}
```

The relevant program code is:

```
struct record {
        const char *name;
        struct record *next;
};
struct record *head;
struct record *tail;

struct record *find_name(const char *name)
{
        struct record *tmp=0;

        if(record_count==0) { // First record 
        cout << "Creating first record" << endl;
        head=new record;
        head->name=name;
        head->next=0;
        tail=head;
        record_count++;
        return head;
        } else {
        tmp=head;
        while(tmp!=0) {
        if(!std::strcmp(tmp->name,name)) {
        cout << "Returning existing record with value: " << "name: " << name << "tmp->name: " << tmp->name << endl;
        return tmp;}
        tmp=tmp->next;
        }

        // No first and no existing records
        cout << "Creating new record" << endl;

        tail->next=new record;
        tail=tail->next;
        tail->name=name;
        tail->next=0;
        record_count++;
        return tail;
        }

}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
struct record *tmp=0;

            if(something is true) {
            //Return or create a new user
            tmp=find_name("Peter");

            } else {
            tmp=find_name("Unknown"); // Hold 1 unknown person in database
            }
}
```

I know it's not compilable as-is but i had to extract it from a larger part.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Would it work to use std::list? or is that not allowed?

Comment: Please post some code which uses this in a way that exhibits the issue you're mentioning.

Comment: This is some C code written as C++. If you want C++ list, use C++ stuff as `std:list`. If it is for school and you are not allowed, think about a class that can handle your concept, and use C++ modern stuff as `std::unique_ptr`, etc...

Comment: @nathanOliver yes i should. I know where it's going from, i'm pretty sure somehow the head pointer gets overwritten each time. Either because i'm doing something i shouldn't, like overwriting a string literal which is const or something else. But i'll have a look at those links.

Comment: @stefaanv i haven't looked into that yet, might do. But i'm a noob programmer and i just wanted some simple code.

Comment: @Boiethios you're probably right. I just started to learn c++ so there's still a lot of c code in there.

Comment: Stop putting `struct` on declarations of instances of the type. That's archaic C, it just adds noise. If you want to learn C++, forget what you know about C and learn C++, use its idioms and facilities. Writing C with a C++ compiler is a waste and teaches you nothing. For this, you would want to use [`std::set< std::string >`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: @AlefVeld -- I have yet to see a beginner in C++ write a correct linked list without a lot of help from experienced programmers.  If this is not a school assignment, use `std::list` or another container class and forget about trying this.  If this is a school assignment,  the best way to know how to properly see how a linked list class is put together is to take a shortcut -- get code that already exists in C++ that does this correctly and study it, compile it, use the debugger to step through the code, etc.

Comment: try dry run your code to understand where your logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not told us what the `records` structure is, there is no way for anyone to give a correct answer. You have made it even more impossible by not giving an example of code that will cause your function to behave incorrectly.

If the `name` element is a `char *` pointer then you could easily get this behaviour. For example:

1. The calling code puts a name into a buffer, and calls `find_name`.
2. `find_name` *stores the address of the buffer* into the `name` element of a `records` object. `name` therefore points to whatever the buffer happens to contain, now and in the future.
3. The calling code puts a new name into the same buffer. This automatically means that the `name` element now points to that new name, since it is pointing to the buffer.
4. The calling code calls `find_name` again.
5. `find_name` compares the contents of the buffer to the string pointed to by the `name` element of the first `records` object. Since the `name` element contains the address of the buffer passed by the caller (from step 2), this means that it is comparing the buffer to itself. So the result is always "equal".

But it may be that `name` is not a pointer at all, in which case this entire answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Then my answer is probably correct. You are not storing a string in `name`, but a pointer to a buffer that has been filled by the caller and passed into the function.

Comment: Updated with struct format and relevant code. Your answer sounds like this might be the case. Are you saying when i call from main and pass the string (i.e. "Ted") to find_name and it updates the member tmp->name, it will loose the pointer at some point. That's what seems to be happening. So how should i store a name in that case, should i copy dereference the actual value and copy that into the member tmp->name ?

Comment: Actually, the function i use to fill in the find_name() returns a string (assuming std::string class). Should that not work ? How else can i fill in a const char for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use the following code formatting

```
    if(record_count==0) { // First record 
    cout << "Creating first record" << endl;
    //...
    } else {
    tmp=head;
    //...
```

It is difficult to read such a code. It is just a bad style of programming.

The function itself can look the following way

```
struct l_list * find_name( const char *name )
{
    struct l_list *tmp = head;

    wjile ( tmp != nullptr && std::strcmp( tmp->name, name ) != 0 ) tmp = tmp->next;

    if ( tmp == nullptr )
    {
        cout << "Creating new record" << endl;
        tmp = new l_list;
        tmp->name = name;            
        tmp->next = nullptr;

        if ( tail == nullptr )
        {
            head = tail = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = tail->next = tmp;
        }

        records++;
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Take into account that the nodes can contain pointers to strings either with the static storage duration as for example string literals or allocated in the heap.

Comment: Thanks, yes i'm starting to realise that. The function i use to get me a name returns a string find_name(function_that_returns_name)). So if i assign a string literal passed on like above, should that work?